# Regex to check if valid URL is either a Youtube VIDEO or IMAGE URL

Tags: regex, validation, jquery-validate, url-validation

So i have a form that let users upload pictures and youtube videos by URL.

I'm using jquery validation plugin to validate the URL of the images like this :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("complete_url", function(val, elem) {
    // if no url, don't do anything
    if (val.length == 0) { return true; }

    // if user has not entered http:// https:// or ftp:// assume they mean http://
    if(!/^(https?|ftp):\/\//i.test(val)) {
        val = 'http://'+val; // set both the value
        $(elem).val(val); // also update the form element
    }
    // now check if valid url
    // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url
    // contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/iri/
    return /^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i.test(val);
});
```

And then :

```
$( "#urlpostform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    imageurl: {
      required: true,
      complete_url: true
    }
```

This is how i check that the submitted url ends in JPG|PNG|JPEG|GIF and its working.

Now i want to add the condition to validate if the submitted url is ether a Youtube video or an IMAGE.

This is the regex to check if submitted url is a youtube video:

```
^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=[^?]*v=\w+)(?:[^\s?]+)?$
```

But i don't know how to make it work together in the same input to validate ether youtube url or image url.

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no means of testing but perhaps something like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("complete_url", function(val, elem) {
// if no url, don't do anything
if (val.length == 0) { return true; }

// if user has not entered http:// https:// or ftp:// assume they mean http://
if(!/^(https?|ftp):\/\//i.test(val)) {
    val = 'http://'+val; // set both the value
    $(elem).val(val); // also update the form element
}

var imgRegex = new Regex("/^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&amp;'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?\. (gif|jpg|jpeg|png))";
var youtubeRegex = new Regex("^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=[^?]*v=\w+)(?:[^\s?]+)?$");

//determine the url
if(imgRegex.test(val) == true)
    return true;
else if(youtubeRegex.test(val) == true)
    return true;
else
    return false;
});
```

The above will first check if it is an image and if it isn't it will check if it is a Youtube URL. The other function remains the same:

```
$( "#urlpostform" ).validate({
rules: {
imageurl: {
  required: true,
  complete_url: true
}
```

Is this something like what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

This worked too,

```
$.validator.addMethod("youtube_url",function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || /^https:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=[^?]*v=\w+)(?:[^\s?]+)?$/i.test(value); 
            },
            "Invalid Youtube Url"
    );


$( "#urlpostform" ).validate({
rules: {
imageurl: {
  required: true,
  youtube_url: true
}
```